# adding date field in html railway booking page

Tags: php, html, datepicker

I've created one railway ticket booking page in `html`. In that form are option where the user is going to fill fields like start `station`, `reach station` and `date`. How can I show a `date`, that appears when the user click on date, means it shows like a calender and the user can select the appropriate date, when the user plans to travel. I want to show next three month in the date from and highlight the current day. We give permission to book the ticket three month ahead the actual journey. Could anyone give me an idea how I could implement this?
..and further when the user has selected the date, how can I get that selected date?

Comment: Why have you tagged your question `php`?

Comment: Please provide your scaffold, which you have already created.

Comment: You can use: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Either with new HTML5 `date` input type: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Or with Javascript addons/libraries, such as JQuery UI's Datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

After the user selects date, it will set the appropriate value of the client-side  element, which you can parse in PHP (e.g. `strtotime()` )

Answer (score 0):

Jquery datepicker will be a good solution for you:
Here you can see this: 
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars

Demo code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display multiple months</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
numberOfMonths: 3,
showButtonPanel: true
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name ="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Documentation : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

In your php page where you will submit form data you can get date picker value by its name for above:

```
$_POST['datepicker'];
```

I think it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html5 date picker

```
<form action="date.php">
Date: <input type="date" name="date">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

split the date to an array

```
<?php
 if($_GET){
    $date=explode('-',$_GET['date']);
    print_r($date);
 }
```

?>